# Generating menu in ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, xml

[image]

I want to change GUI menu of ubuntu. That is, I want to add a icon at the menu (top of screen), after clicking that a menu will be shown and selecting particular option will run a particular command.

Can some please help me

Comment: do you have the option to alt-right click on the bar?

Comment: I am using gnome there is no such option on bar....I have added my desktop image in question

Comment: In gnome session fallback I have that option - sorry I can't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a simple python applet.
Here is a very simple applet I have which I have noted where to put your commands and names for the commands:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import gtk
import appindicator
import subprocess
import os

repo_name = "Name Of Indicator"

def sh_escape(s):
    return s.replace("\"","\\\"")

class Commands:
    def __init__(self, title="Unknown", command=""):
        self.title = title
        self.command = command

commandArr = [];
commandArr.append(Commands("Command 1 name","command one"))
commandArr.append(Commands("Command 2 name","command two"))


class RemoteApplet:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ind = appindicator.Indicator(repo_name,
                                           repo_name,
                                           appindicator.CATEGORY_APPLICATION_STATUS)
        self.ind.set_label(repo_name)
        self.ind.set_status(appindicator.STATUS_ACTIVE)
        self.ind.set_attention_icon("new-messages-red")

        self.menu_setup()
        self.ind.set_menu(self.menu)

    def menu_setup(self):
        self.menu = gtk.Menu()
        self.command_items = []
        cnt = 0
        for x in commandArr:
            self.command_items.append(gtk.MenuItem(x.title))
            self.command_items[-1].connect("activate", self.handleitem, cnt)
            self.command_items[-1].show()
            self.menu.append(self.command_items[-1])
            cnt += 1
        self.quit_item = gtk.MenuItem("Quit")
        self.quit_item.connect("activate", self.quit)
        self.quit_item.show()
        self.menu.append(self.quit_item)

    def main(self):
        self.login()
        print "Started!"
        gtk.main()

    def quit(self, widget):
        sys.exit(0)

    def login(self):
        pass

    def handleitem(self, widget, index):
        print "Running... " + commandArr[index].command
        proc = subprocess.Popen(commandArr[index].command,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
        (out, err) = proc.communicate()
        os.system("/usr/bin/notify-send \"" + sh_escape(repo_name + " - Output") + "\" \"" + sh_escape(out) + "\"")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "Starting..."
    indicator = RemoteApplet()
    indicator.main()
```

Comment: But how can I create icon and by clicking on that I can run my commands.

Comment: I would assume you would instead or running the line `self.ind.set_label(repo_name)` run `self.ind.set_icon('path-to-icon.jpg')'

Comment: This code only works in unity how to make it work in gnome.

Comment: There is a bottom bar in Gnome 3 that has your applets. The applet will be there.